# Web service only works in root folder

Tags: c#, web-services

So i have a Webservice that works fine when i upload it to the root directory

www.mysite.com/service.asmx

but if i upload it to another folder i get the following result.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /test/service.asmx

if they are both are uploaded at once the one in the test folder refers to the root directory even tho they might contain different code.

Any ideas, if this isn't clear enough just write your question and ill reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create the virutual folder (in this case 'test') then you need to upload to that .

It's like telling server interpret the folder path (for e.g c:\web\mysite\test) as \test context path.

Assuming you are using IIS , you can create a virtual directory using [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138)